# How to get internal/external available space in Android Application?

Tags: android, storage, android-sdcard, diskspace

I'm writing an android program to check available space of internal phone memory or external sd card. But i don't know how to do this. Any one can help me how to do it in Android?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for this class: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html